# Como mostrar o estoque de produtos configuráveis no Magento

Tags: php, magento

Boa tarde!

Estou apanhando aqui para resolver esta questão. Em minha loja, os produtos configuráveis até aparecem o estoque, mas o primeiro item aparece como "null". Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha versão de trabalho é a 1.9.1.0.

Esse é o trecho do meu arquivo, onde foi feita a modificação: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php

```
$simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productsIndex); 
$qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleproduct)->getQty();

$info['options'][] = array(
'id'        => $value['value_index'],
'label'     => $value['label'],
'price'     => $configurablePrice,
'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
'products'  => $productsIndex,
'qty'       => $qty, // we are sending stock parameter so we can use it latter in drop down field
);
```

Alguma sugestão? Já pesquisei bastante no Google, fiz diversos testes, mas sem sucesso!

Agradeço a todos!

---

Para mostrar o estoque como na imagem, segui esta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319680/show-stock-of-configurable-products-on-magento-1-9